# HTML: Track when an element changes from readonly to not readonly?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, google-chrome-devtools

I'm looking for a solution to track when an HTML element (tag, like a textarea input box) changes from attribute 'readonly' to being not read-only (having the attribute removed as far as I can tell). I'm not yet finding a way to do this in Chrome Dev Tools or vanilla JavaScript or jQuery (I haven't used Firefox for web dev in a long time, sorry).

If I can catch that, and print it out to console.log, that would be great so then I could trace when it's happening, since I'm unable to reproduce a bug the user is reporting under some circumstance.

I've seen some things about MutationObserver though that appears to be an abandoned project and I'm not sure that's a good path to go down. I know I can look up some events in Chrome Dev Tools, but maybe I'm just not seeing what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) isn't abandoned all, it's a modern browser API and could do the job for you. There is an [example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver#example) on that page, that you could use almost of the box.

This is the part you would need to work with:

```js
// modify this to check if `mutation.attributeName` === `readonly`
if (mutation.type === 'attributes') {
    console.log('The ' + mutation.attributeName + ' attribute was modified.');
}
```